# ability to turn off gravatar in seach results of careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Joel and Jeff discussed on the latest blog podcast that gravatars show up in the search results.  They also suggested people not use the ip gravatars or other non-serious ones.

A better solution is to allow users to choose whether the their gravatar shows up in search results.